# Hot to decide which asset bundle varient of xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi or ldpi should be picked in unity3d game to have decent UI with out pixelated?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

While designing UI in unity. If I directly attach single mdpi image and text in different resolution the images/sprite are scaling as per screen size.But the problem is when the image is scaled its getting displayed as pixelated?

So I read about asset bundle variants and trying to use them by making different bundles for different resolutions. (bundles varients are xxxhdpi, xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi and ldpi).

But I am stuck at how to pick the asset bundle variant for the device that my game is running.How to use `Screen.dpi` in unity to achieve that ?

I am assuming I can do the same for both Android(phones and Tabs) and IOS(iPhones and iPads) devices as well.

Answer (score 0):

The table is following:

- MDPI - 160dpi
- HDPI - 240dpi
- XHDPI - 320dpi
- XXHDPI - 480dpi
- XXXHDPI - 680dpi

So the check would be:

```
void Start(){
    if(Screen.dpi <= 160){
        //change your UI textures for mdpi
    }else if(Screen.dpi <= 240){
        //change your UI textures for hdpi
    }else if(Screen.dpi <= 320){
        //change your UI textures for xhdpi
    }else if(Screen.dpi <= 480){
        //change your UI textures for xxhdpi
    }else{
        //change your UI textures for xxxhdpi
    }
}
```

Edit: Be aware that maybe Unity changed shape of returned value. Play with it to see what's it's returning if this isn't correct. Also, see [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-dpi.html) and [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/screen-dpi-on-android.414014/).